# Spring Boot not picking up properties from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I have a small spring-boot application, where I am trying to pickup properties from `application.properties` into my `@Component` class.

However, I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bucket4jRateLimiterV2' defined in file [/Users/npatira/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.3.RELEASE/assessment/target/classes/com/nishit/ninesixteen/listener/Bucket4jRateLimiterV2.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.nishit.ninesixteen.listener.Bucket4jRateLimiterV2]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is wrong value for period tokens, because tokens should be positive
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.nishit.ninesixteen.listener.Bucket4jRateLimiterV2]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is wrong value for period tokens, because tokens should be positive
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is wrong value for period tokens, because tokens should be positive
    at io.github.bucket4j.BucketExceptions.nonPositivePeriodTokens(BucketExceptions.java:106)
    at io.github.bucket4j.Refill.<init>(Refill.java:46)
    at io.github.bucket4j.Refill.intervally(Refill.java:108)
    at com.nishit.ninesixteen.listener.Bucket4jRateLimiterV2.<init>(Bucket4jRateLimiterV2.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

My interpretation of this error is that it has not been able to pick up either the value from `application.properties` or the default value assigned.

Below is the code for the Component.

```
@Component
public class Bucket4jRateLimiterV2 {

        @Value("${ratelimit:100}")
    private int throttleRate;

    @Value("${thrrotleDuration:1}")
    private int refillDuration;

    private Refill refill;

    private Bandwidth limit;

    private Bucket BUCKET;

    public Bucket4jRateLimiterV2() {
        System.out.println("Values are : " + throttleRate + " " + refillDuration);
        refill = Refill.intervally(throttleRate, Duration.ofMinutes(refillDuration));
        limit = Bandwidth.classic(5, refill);
        BUCKET = Bucket4j.builder().addLimit(limit).build();
    }

    public boolean isAPICallAllowed() {
        System.out.println("thrrotleRate : " + throttleRate);
        System.out.println("Available tokens are  : " + BUCKET.getAvailableTokens() + " called from thread : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return BUCKET.tryConsume(TOKEN_COUNT);
    }
}
```

This gave an output

```
Values are : 0 0
```

which means the `int` were initialized without picking up the value from the properties file.

and this is how my `application.properties` looks

```
ratelimit = 500
throttleDuration = 1
```

My main class has the following annotations.

```
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nishit")
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

**What have I tried?**

1. I first thought that `application.properties` is not in my classpath. Verified that.
2. I tried `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller` in all these annotations, to see if the property gets picked up somewhere.

Any idea of what it is that I have done wrong?

Comment: "IllegalArgumentException: 0 is wrong value for period tokens, because tokens should be positive"
Which line is 24 of Bucket4jRateLimiterV2.java? What is failing there?

Comment: It should work! I ran it, and it just worked fine (I mean reading values from the properties file). It will help if you search for the problem(s) elsewhere in your POJO(s), or anywhere you handle your logic.
The exception addresses the `wrong value for period tokens`.

Comment: @Howard007 Line 24 is `private final Refill refill = Refill.intervally(throttleRate, Duration.ofMinutes(refillDuration));
` where the values of throttleRate and refillDuration are being used.

Comment: @HadiRasouli I added print statement in the constructor to get the values of the fields I am setting via application.properties. Have updated the output in the question. It is very clearly, not able to pick the values from the properties file (since the value is set to 0, default int value)

Comment: I assume that your application.properties file is in main/resources. Is it the only one? Are there any environment variables in play? i.e. is it looking for application-dev.properties or application-prod.properties? Are you running it in your IDE or java -JAR?

Comment: @Howard007 There is just 1 application.properties, no application-{env}. Running it from the IDE (Spring Tool Suite 4). Not setting any other env variables.

Comment: @Nishit, check this image, create a new spring boot project(to test it) and try to read the values from the `application.properties` . You can see that your code reads values from the properties file just fine.

Please check this image:
https://pasteboard.co/GX99BYzDEhFh.png

Comment: @HadiRasouli Thanks for that. Looks like I was using the properties in a wrong way. I was trying to use those properties to initialize some other fields in the constructor. However, the property values are still not set at that time. I just moved my initialization to a `@PostConstruct` and things were working fine. So, the problem was the way I was using the properties. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try,This works with [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j) as well.